# SQL: Failed to add the Foreign Key

Tags: sql

I am currently using PopSQL for my school project. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory. You need an index on the column that the foreign key refers to.

So, do create it:

```
create index idx_section_sectno on section(sectno):
```

Also, you might want to read the [MySQL documentation for foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Other conditions apply to forein keys that you want to be aware of.